# Adjusting extruder

Tags: prusa-i3, extruder, calibration, geeetech

Since I have some problems with printing I wanted to try to adjust my extruder esteps. While changing the esteps I noticed that the value has almost no impact. My default setting was 93 and the calculation went from iteration to iteration up to 375. Then I just tried my luck with 450 and then 75 the results were all crap.

Then I notices that the filament didn't move as fast as the stepper motor. So I guess there is the problem. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to calibrate though a hot nozzle or with the bowden tube disconnected?
You may also need to adjust the tension on your extruder gear.

Comment: I heated the hotend to 180°C with the nozzle for my PLA filament. Do you have a reference for adjusting the tension of the extruder gear? Seems logic for me but I have no idea

Comment: That's way too cold, and you were probably trying to calibrate too fast. I always calibrate my e-steps with the bowden or nozzle removed.

Extruder gear tension is tricky. Too low tension can cause it to skip over the filament, too high tension can cause the motor to lose steps. If you can *see* the filament being ground off by the wheel, you'll probably need more tension (if it's adjustable at all on your printer).

Comment: Thank you for your hints I'll try it later again, which temperature do you use?

Comment: Cold, with the bowden tube (bowden) or nozzle (direct drive) removed ;)

Comment: Also, go back to 80-ish steps/mm for now